# how do i loop my javascript with the same number of looped data?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

[image: This is my view page as u can see on the first row of data is hit by the Javascript while the other data status is not showing status]

this is the javscript that i wanna run on all row of data

```js
<script>
        
          function status(a,b){
                if (a == b){
                   return 'Paid'
                } else {
                    return 'Not Paid'
                }
            }
           
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status({{$borrows->amount}},{{$borrows->amount_paid}}); 
  
</script>
```

and this is my html

```html
<table style="width:50%">
        <div>
            <tr>enter code here
               `<th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>
             
            </tr>
            @foreach ($borrows as $borrows)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$borrows->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$borrows->amount}}</td>
                <td id="status"></td>
            
            </tr>
        </div>
```

this is my current backend code
public function index()
{

```
    $borrows = borrows::orderby('name','desc')->paginate(10);
    print($borrows);
    return view('borrowshome')->with('borrows',$borrows);
   
    
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, `div` is not a permitted content directly in [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) element. I'd suggest you to include `thead` and `tbody` tags in the table, then you could get a collection of the datarows: `tbody.rows`, which you can iterate.

Comment: it will better if you get this information from the backend